# Save image from ImageView to device gallery

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, android-gallery

I'm trying to save an image from ImageView to devices gallery.
I tried this code

Code Edit:

```
    URL url = new URL(getIntent().getStringExtra("imageURL"));
    File f  = new File(url.getPath());

    addImageToGallery(f.getPath(), this);

    public static void addImageToGallery(final String filePath, final Context context) 
    {

       ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

       values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
       values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
       values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, filePath);

       context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
    }
```

but it requires a file path in which I don't have since I'm loading the file from a URL.
How can I save an image from ImageView to the gallery?

thanks..

Comment: Save the file to the sdcard first....

Comment: Not all devices can have SDCard (Nexus 5 for example)

Comment: All devices have storage... dont be so hard on me...

Comment: Ok so it might be a misunderstaing by me, but sdcard means internal storage as well?

Comment: Nope of course not ;) I just ment to say you should save the file some where ;)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Simple:

use this code:

```
//to get the image from the ImageView (say iv)
BitmapDrawable draw = (BitmapDrawable) iv.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = draw.getBitmap();

FileOutputStream outStream = null;
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/YourFolderName");
dir.mkdirs();
String fileName = String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());
File outFile = new File(dir, fileName);
outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
outStream.flush();
outStream.close();
```

Additionally, in order to refresh the gallery and to view the image there:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
    sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Also make sure that your app has the storage permission enabled:

Go to Device Settings>Device>Applications>Application Manager>"your app">Permissions>Enable Storage permission!

Manifest permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the late comment! I actually found a solution for this issue, but yours seems to work as well. Thanks!

Comment: can you share your solution that you found?

Comment: For the latest android versions add this line to Manifest.xml : android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"

Comment: @Coderminion android 11 will simply ignore this android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true". Workaround is compiling it with 29 API.

Answer (score 4):

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.your_image_view);
```

Then set your image and when you want to retrieve/save it

```
iv.buildDrawingCache();

Bitmap bmp = iv.getDrawingCache();
```

Then save as normal to gallery

```
    File storageLoc = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES); //context.getExternalFilesDir(null);

    File file = new File(storageLoc, filename + ".jpg");

    try{
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.close();

        scanFile(context, Uri.fromFile(file));

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    private static void scanFile(Context context, Uri imageUri){
        Intent scanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        scanIntent.setData(imageUri);
        context.sendBroadcast(scanIntent);

    }
```

and of course make sure your manifest has permissions to write to external storage.

Answer (score -1):

U can easily get a file from URL

```
File f = new File(url.getPath());
```

Comment: Well, now I have the path to it (or is it just a URL?) but when it saves the picture I get a black picture..

Comment: can u please update ur question with the code where u r doing this all stuff

Comment: that seems fine. but i meant the code that converts imageview to bitmap and all that.

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320094/how-to-save-an-image-from-an-imageview-after-taking-a-picture. let me know if u still have ny problem