# Get Output Cropped Image URI

Tags: android, image, android-intent, crop

I have implemented image cropping in my app using android intent like below:

```
CropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
```

I have received the cropped image and displayed on my UI but I want to perform further use cases like upload the cropped image uri. The problem is that no uri is returned in activity.

Here's my crop image intent snippet:

```
galleryFAB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Gallery Btn Clicked");
            selectFromGallery();
        }
    });

private void selectFromGallery() {

    galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Choose From"), 2);
}
```

my code in activity result method:

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    InputStream inputStream;

    if (requestCode == 2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        if (data != null){
            cropImageUri = data.getData();
            userImage.setImageURI(cropImageUri);
            try {
                originalBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), cropImageUri);

                inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
                originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

                Log.d(TAG, "Original bitmap byte count is:\t" + originalBitmap.getByteCount());

                resizedBitmap = getResizedBitmap(originalBitmap, 200);

                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                resizedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

                Log.d(TAG, "Resized bitmap byte count is:\t" + resizedBitmap.getByteCount());

                try {
                    File file = saveBitmap("avatar_image");
                    upLoadFile(file);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }


                byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();

                /**
                 *   For Shared Preferences
                 * **/

                encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);

                imagePrefs = getSharedPreferences("ImagePrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = imagePrefs.edit();
                editor.putString("image_user", encodedImage).commit();

                upLoadBytes(bytes);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            cropImage();
        }

    } else if (requestCode == PERM_CODE){
        if (data != null){

            //I want to get the cropped image uri here but unable to. Have tried converting the bitmap rcvd here to uri but in activity, ntn is returned. kindly guide me

            Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
            originalBitmap = bundle.getParcelable("data");
            userImage.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);
        }

    }

}
```

my crop image function:

```
private void cropImage() {
    try {
        CropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");

        CropIntent.setDataAndType(cropImageUri, "image/*");
        CropIntent.putExtra("crop", true);
        CropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
        CropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
        CropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        CropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        CropIntent.putExtra("scale", true);
        CropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);

        startActivityForResult(CropIntent, PERM_CODE);


    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex){

    }
}
```

Can anyone say how to get the output uri? Thanks.

Comment: Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`. There are many [image-cropping libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45). Please use one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the cropped image is showing in an ImageView, follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38904444/7248857) to save it to device storage, then you can upload the file.